# Can't send E-Mails with Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I have this code as I am trying to send E-Mails using Python.

```
def Mail():
   import smtplib
   import textwrap
   SERVER = "localhost"

   FROM = "fromemail"
   TO = ["toemail"] 

   SUBJECT =(input('What is the subject of your E-Mail'))

   TEXT =(input('What do you want the E-Mail to say?'))

   message = textwrap.dedent("""\
   From: %s
   To: %s
   Subject: %s

   %s
   """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT))

   server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
   server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
   server.quit()
```

This is the error message I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    Mail()
  File "E:\Coursework\EMail.py", line 26, in Mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
  File "C:\Python33\python-3.3.5\lib\smtplib.py", line 241, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python33\python-3.3.5\lib\smtplib.py", line 322, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Python33\python-3.3.5\lib\smtplib.py", line 375, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: Is a mail server (perhaps `smtpd` or `sendmail`) running on your computer?  If not, that would explain your error, as there is nothing to connect to on localhost.

Comment: Do you get SMTP greeting message using `telnet localhost 25`? [Translated: Is it python fault?]

Comment: How would one know if a mail server is running? I have an ability to send/retrieve e-mails.

Comment: Is there an easy way of sending e-mails via python?

Answer (score 1):

The 'Connection unexpectedly closed' shows that the server is probably ON but unable to create a connection to smtplib.

You could check the status of the port 25 smtp service to verify that,

`# netstat -an | grep -i :25
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Then, check the status of the service occupying the port 25,

`# netstat -plnt | grep -i :25
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30860/master`

You probably will have the same,
then just check the status of the master/postfix process,

`# systemctl status postfix`

If you get the error highlighted as,

**fatal: cannot handle socket type AF_INET6 with "inet_protocols = ipv4"**

then quickly go to the postfix configuration file at ***/etc/postfix/main.cf*** and check if you have this text and uncomment it,

**inet_protocols = ipv4**

Then restart postfix,

`# systemctl restart postfix`

then check status, hopefully you shouldn't get any errors.
Then check if python is able to connect to the SMTP server!

`$ python -c 'import smtplib; smtplib.SMTP("localhost");'`

You shouldn't get any output which shows that python is able to connect to the SMTP server.

you can run your email sending script now!